# SQL Server : calculation stored procedure

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, label

How to write a stored procedure to return a running total?

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspGetPackStatisticsPerShift]
    @ShiftStart DATETIME,
    @ShiftEnd DATETIME,
    @SeriesMasterId INT
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    --DECLARE @LogicalMachineId int
    --DECLARE @WorkCellId int

    --SELECT @LogicalMachineId = mr.LogicalMachineId, @WorkCellId = lm.WorkCellId
    --FROM Shared.dbo.MachineRegistry mr
    --INNER JOIN Shared.dbo.LogicalMachine lm on lm.Id = mr.LogicalMachineId and lm.Active=1
    --WHERE mr.Active=1 AND mr.SystemId = 'Generic' AND mr.DnsName = @MachineName 

    --IF (@WorkCellId IS NULL)
    --BEGIN
    --  RAISERROR('uspGetBuildStatisticsPerShift() Workstation not defined', 15, 1)
    --  RETURN
    --END

    -- Now get the data
    SELECT
        DATEDIFF(hour, @ShiftStart, psh.DtTmEnd) + 1  AS ShiftHour,
        ifsm.[Id] AS FrameSizeMasterId,
        COUNT(ph.Id) AS TotalPacked
    FROM
        Production.dbo.PackHistory ph
    INNER JOIN 
        Production.dbo.PackStageHistory psh ON psh.PackHistoryId = ph.Id 
                                            AND psh.PackScheduleStageID = 2
    INNER JOIN 
        Production.dbo.ItemSerialNumber isn ON isn.Id = ph.ItemSerialNumberId
    INNER JOIN 
        Production.dbo.ItemMaster im ON im.Id = isn.ItemMasterId
    INNER JOIN 
        Production.dbo.ItemSeriesMaster ism ON ism.Id = im.SeriesMasterId 
                                            AND im.SeriesMasterId =  @SeriesMasterId
    INNER JOIN 
        Production.dbo.ItemFrameSizeMaster ifsm ON ifsm.Id = im.FrameSizeMasterId
    WHERE
        psh.DtTmEnd BETWEEN @ShiftStart AND @ShiftEnd 
        AND psh.Successful = 1 
        AND psh.ReRun = 0
    GROUP BY
        DATEDIFF(hour, @ShiftStart, psh.DtTmEnd) + 1, ifsm.[Id]   
    ORDER BY
        1
```

This stored procedure returns the total of units packed per shift.. what I need is a stored procedure that will return the total units packed as a running total.

And finally I have a label that I want to pass this value to.. how can I make the label update after each unit is packed? I already have my page refreshing after 1 minute to reflect the changes but not sure how to add a stored procedure to a label in aspx c#

So this is what my stored proc outputs https://ibb.co/jOEkfy

And now i need to pass these values to a aspx label, and then reset after 8 hours.

Comment: Which RDBMS you are using ?

Comment: Simply apply a *Windowed Aggregate*: `sum(Count(ph.Id )) over (order by DateDiff(hour, @ShiftStart, psh.DtTmEnd) + 1 rows unbounded preceding)`

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by running total here, the proc can return values, but each execution of the proc is independent. Do you want to make an execution know about prior returned values? Or do you just want it to total a specific range

Comment: I am using sql server management studio.. And i am new to writing these stored procs, this one above was written by someone else.. what it returns is just a table of stats, e.g total units packed... A = 29 AA=33 B=23 C=22 ... i just need to keep adding up the units and output this to a label in visual studio that refreshes every 60 seconds.

Comment: anyone help please?

Comment: it would help us understand what you want if you edit your question and add sample data and expected outcome

Comment: I have added a screenshot an a bit more details

Comment: https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/06/bad-habits-to-kick-order-by-ordinal

Comment: What we really need is details of your tables and what you want as output. But please not images. Why? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557 Here is a better approach. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/